# Multiplicación de variables en Bash

Tags: bash, variables

Estoy trabajando con *Bash*, e intento hacer un programa que calcule lo que una persona gana según las horas que trabajo.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
echo "No has ingresado los parámetros correctos para el sistema"
echo "El uso correcto es labo2.sh codigo_empleado filename"
exit
fi
dia=0
noche=0
pago=0
for i in `grep $1 $2 | cut -d ";" -f3`;
do
dia=$(($dia+$i))
noche=$(($noche+$i))
done
for m in `grep $1 $2 | cut -d ";" -f5`;
do
pago=$m
echo "pago $pago"
done
horas=$(($dia+$noche))
echo "dia $dia noche $noche"
sueldo=$(`expr $horas \* $pago`)
echo "pago $pago, horas $horas, sueldo $sueldo"
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me tira el siguiente error

> expr: argumento no entero

Pero intente hacer así:

```
sueldo=$(echo "scale=2; $horas*$pago" | bc)
```

... y al hacerlo de esa manera me tira este error:

```
    (standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
```

Dejo el archivo de texto con el que estoy trabajando aquí:

```
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 11 ; 11 ; 2
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 21 ; 21 ; 2
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 6 ; 6 ; 2
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 15 ; 15 ; 2
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 18 ; 18 ; 2
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 12 ; 12 ; 2
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 28 ; 28 ; 2
50 ; ARDON MARTA AMALIA ; 22 ; 22 ; 2
350 ; PEREZ MARTINEZ MARIA ; 9 ; 9 ; 3
350 ; PEREZ MARTINEZ MARIA ; 8 ; 8 ; 3
350 ; PEREZ MARTINEZ MARIA ; 11 ; 11 ; 3
350 ; PEREZ MARTINEZ MARIA ; 14 ; 14 ; 3
350 ; PEREZ MARTINEZ MARIA ; 14 ; 14 ; 3
350 ; PEREZ MARTINEZ MARIA ; 14 ; 14 ; 3
350 ; PEREZ MARTINEZ MARIA ; 14 ; 14 ; 3
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 31 ; 31 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 20 ; 20 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 21 ; 21 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 26 ; 26 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 23 ; 23 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 23 ; 23 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 22 ; 22 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 179 ; 179 ; 2
420 ; MUSUN AGUILAR ETELVINA ; 240 ; 240 ; 2
600 ; ALFARO DE MIRANDA MIRNA ; 7 ; 7 ; 4
600 ; ALFARO DE MIRANDA MIRNA ; 28 ; 28 ; 4
600 ; ALFARO DE MIRANDA MIRNA ; 23 ; 23 ; 4
600 ; ALFARO DE MIRANDA MIRNA ; 37 ; 37 ; 4
600 ; ALFARO DE MIRANDA MIRNA ; 6 ; 6 ; 4
600 ; ALFARO DE MIRANDA MIRNA ; 28 ; 28 ; 4
610 ; RODRIGUEZ AMANDA LIDIA ; 16 ; 16 ; 2
610 ; RODRIGUEZ AMANDA LIDIA ; 8 ; 8 ; 2
610 ; RODRIGUEZ AMANDA LIDIA ; 8 ; 8 ; 2
830 ; GONZALES DE CARIAS MARIA ; 131 ; 131 ; 3
830 ; GONZALES DE CARIAS MARIA ; 27 ; 27 ; 3
830 ; GONZALES DE CARIAS MARIA ; 45 ; 45 ; 3
830 ; GONZALES DE CARIAS MARIA ; 60 ; 60 ; 3
830 ; GONZALES DE CARIAS MARIA ; 75 ; 75 ; 3
830 ; GONZALES DE CARIAS MARIA ; 51 ; 51 ; 3
830 ; GONZALES DE CARIAS MARIA ; 70 ; 70 ; 3
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 8 ; 8 ; 4
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 16 ; 16 ; 4
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 13 ; 13 ; 4
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 14 ; 14 ; 4
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 12 ; 12 ; 4
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 17 ; 17 ; 4
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 7 ; 7 ; 4
890 ; NERIO SANCHEZ ANA VILMA ; 7 ; 7 ; 4
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 6 ; 6 ; 3
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 8 ; 8 ; 3
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 9 ; 9 ; 3
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 11 ; 11 ; 3
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 6 ; 6 ; 3
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 15 ; 15 ; 3
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 10 ; 10 ; 3
940 ; SALAZAR LORENA ANGELICA ; 13 ; 13 ; 3
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 29 ; 29 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 52 ; 52 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 16 ; 16 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 8 ; 8 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 12 ; 12 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 8 ; 8 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 18 ; 18 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 18 ; 18 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 28 ; 28 ; 4
2120 ; GALDAMEZ ZALDA�A WALTER ; 35 ; 35 ; 4
2130 ; CRUZ SANTOS DALIA TERESA ; 6 ; 6 ; 3
2130 ; CRUZ SANTOS DALIA TERESA ; 6 ; 6 ; 3
2130 ; CRUZ SANTOS DALIA TERESA ; 9 ; 9 ; 3
2370 ; ALAS CHACON ALEXANDER  ; 12 ; 12 ; 5
2370 ; ALAS CHACON ALEXANDER  ; 30 ; 30 ; 5
2370 ; ALAS CHACON ALEXANDER  ; 540 ; 540 ; 5
2370 ; ALAS CHACON ALEXANDER  ; 480 ; 480 ; 5
2370 ; ALAS CHACON ALEXANDER  ; 8 ; 8 ; 5
```

Por cierto, la estructura del archivo de texto es *codigo_empleado*, *nombre*, *horas_diurnas*, *horas_nocturnas*, *pago_por_hora*.

Answer (score 2):

Tu script funciona bien en el sentido que no da errores, al menos cuando usas:

> sueldo=$(echo "scale=2; $horas*$pago" | bc)

Esta es la salida que me da a mi a modo de ejemplo:

```
$./labo2.sh 350 datos.txt 
pago 3
pago 3
pago 3
pago 3
pago 3
pago 3
pago 3
dia 84 noche 84
pago 3, horas 168, sueldo 504
```

Si a ti te da ese problema me imagino que has hecho un corta y pega desde un archivo codificado desde windows o ms-dos, pues el `^M` no es más que el archiconocido [retorno de carro](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retorno_de_carro) y salto de línea `"\r\n"` que en el mundo unix no usamos, pues marcamos el final de las líneas sólo con `"\n"`

Soluciones para eliminar ese molesto caracter, pues tienes varias:

1. Borrar y volver a escribir esa línea (tal vez funcione).
2. Usar el comando `dos2unix`  en los dos archivos (script-bash y
   datos).
3. Sacarlo con `sed -e "s/\^M//"` filename > newfilename
4. O desde vim usar :%s/^M//g

Según tus gustos ;-)

Comment: en el caso de utilizar el sed -e "s/\^M//" en que parte del codigo lo pondria?

Comment: Lo comentaba para poner directamente en la línea de comandos... pero ahora que comentas podrías ponerlo al principio del script para que limpie de caracteres de retorno de carro el archivo que vaya a procesar :-)

Comment: @JoshuaMejía te fue útil la respuesta??? por cierto. Para lo comentarios, utiliza comentarios. Si puedes eliminar la contestación de abajo, mejor que mejor... pues no es una contestación XD

Comment: Me di cuenta que el archivo de texto estaba creado en windows lo que hice fue crear un archivo nuevo en linux con los mismos datos y funciono!